# How to get all _ids from MongoDB collection in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, find

I want to get all _ids from a MongoDB collection using PHP. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->database->collectionName;

$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach ( $cursor as $id => $value )
{
    var_dump($value['_id']); //Object(MongoId)
}
```

You can read more about MongoId object [here](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mongoid.php)

From the [comments](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mongoid.php#104850):

> If you need to get the actual ID string, and you try the usual way, 
>   PHP will whine because it starts with a dollar sign and it thinks it's
>   a variable. Instead, use this notation:

```
$mongoid->{'$id'} //Get the $id property of a MongoId object
```

Comment: I'll only add that `\MongoId` can be cast to string and `(string) $mongoid` is working perfectly fine